# Dynamic Select Dropdown Menu

Tags: php, html

I have a menu with 3 options, that in the simplest form looks like:

```
<form action="samePageAction" form="post">
  <select>
    <option>Yes</option>
    <option>No</option>
    <option>Maybe</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

It isn't really "dynamic", its just based on a user's setting in the database, I'm choosing what "option" to display by default:

```
    <form action="samePageAction" form="post">
      <select>
<?    
      if(!$personUndecided && $personHasAgreed){
?>   
        <option>Yes</option>
        <option>No</option>
        <option>Maybe</option> 
<?    
      } else if(!$personUndecided && !$personHasAgreed){
?> 
        <option>No</option>
        <option>Yes</option>
        <option>Maybe</option>
      </select>
<?
      else {
?>
        <option>Maybe</option>
        <option>Yes</option>
        <option>No</option>
     </select>
<? } ?>
    </form>
```

The "first" option in each case is important, because when the form is disabled, that is the option the user will see. I feel gross when I look at this, but a better solution isn't coming to me. How can I optimize this menu?

**Question:** How can I prevent repeating myself this much. Or does this code look perfectly normal?

Comment: What you actually looking for ? *Question Is Unclear, My Dear*

Comment: @bruh please note that the `else`statement will never be executed

Comment: Thanks @fusion3k , fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can short your code in this way, i.e.:

```
<?php
   if( $personHasAgreed )      $choices = array ( 'Yes',  'No',  'Maybe' );
   elseif( !$personHasAgreed ) $choices = array ( 'No',   'Yes', 'Maybe' );
   else                        $choices = array ( 'Maybe','Yes', 'No' );

   foreach( $choices as $choice ):
?>
       <option><?php echo $choice; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

In this way you assign first the various choice values depending on `$personHasAgreed` setting, then perform one `foreach` loop to output each option.

Edit: please note that I think the `else` statement will never be executed...

Comment: About the else block, there is another condition (I didn't mention) for example `$personUndecided = true && $personHasAgreed` .... will only hit the 3rd case, as the first 2 would be false. Thanks for pointing that out though!

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution with `explode` function:

```
<form action="samePageAction" form="post">
    <select>
<?php
    $personHasAgreed = "";
    $valueString = ($personHasAgreed === 1)? "Yes,No,Maybe" : (($personHasAgreed === 0)? "No,Yes,Maybe" : "Maybe,Yes,No" );
    $valueString = explode(",", $valueString); 
    foreach($valueString as $word){
        echo "<option>". $word ."<option>";
    }
?>     
      </select>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
<form action="samePageAction" method="post">
    <select>
<?php
$possAnswer = array(
    "1" => "<option>Yes</option>", 
    "0" => "<option>No</option>", 
    "2" => "<option>Maybe</option>"
    );
if($personHasAgreed) {
    echo $possAnswer[1] . $possAnswer[0] . $possAnswer[2];
} else if(!$personHasAgreed ){
    echo $possAnswer[0] . $possAnswer[1] . $possAnswer[2];
} else {
    echo $possAnswer[2] . $possAnswer[1] . $possAnswer[0];
}
?> 
    </select>
</form>
```

`